# Rails use helper method to search for id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok i have an simple input, where the user can typ in an user name, and the helper method finduserid should then search for the right user id:

```
<%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => finduserid(input), :class => "input-small" %>
```

The helper method:

```
def finduserid(name)
  @user = User.find_by_typ(name)
  return @user.id
end
```

First my code dont works because input is an "undefined local variable or method". So how can i change this? And is an helper method the right tool for this task? How would you perform it?

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
<td> <%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => findebmsid(input), :class => "input-small" %>      </td> 
<td></td> 
<td> <%= f.text_field :extra %></td> 
<td> <%= f.hidden_field :number, :value => "1" %></td>    
<td><%= f.submit "Speichern", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think a helper is the correct aproach, you should use the show action on your app something like this:

view:

```
 <%= form_tag(users_path,:method => :get ) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :user_name, params[:user_name] %>               
 <%end%>
```

controller:

```
def show
  @user=User.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
end
```

show view:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Comment: ah sounds good but i have all the stuff in an form to save, i will edit my question.